# What is the name of the design pattern where you have a single-value, strongly typed property container?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Looking for the name of the design pattern by which you have a POJO with public final "properties" where the property acts as a holder/wrapper for a certain type of value and contains the getter/setter for that value as well as potentially some additional logic.

This differs from the "Property Container" design pattern where you have a single properties container which contains many types, as this only holds a single value and can thus enjoy the benefits of remaining strongly typed.

An example use:

```
public class User extends Entity<User> {

    private static final Structure<User> STRUCTURE = Structure.of(User.class, User::new)
        .addPrimaryKey("user_id", UUID).property((e) -> e.userID).setDefault(() -> UUID()).build()
        .addIndex("username", VCHARS_50).property((e) ->  e.username).build()
        .addIndex("email", VCHARS_255).property((e) -> e.email).build()
        .add("password", VCHARS_255).property((e) -> e.passwordHash).build()
        .add("privacy_policy_accepted", EPOCH).property((e) -> e.ppAccepted).setDefault(() -> now()).build()
        .add("tos_accepted", EPOCH).property((e) -> e.tosAccepted).setDefault(() -> now()).build()
        .add("registration_date", EPOCH).property((e) -> e.registrationDate).setDefault(() -> now()).build()
        .buildFor(Schema.MASTER);
 
    public final Property<UUID> userID = new Property<>();
    public final Property<String> username = new Property<>();
    public final Property<String> email = new Property<>();
    public final Property<String> passwordHash = new Property<>();
    public final Property<Long> ppAccepted = new Property<>();
    public final Property<Long> tosAccepted = new Property<>();
    public final Property<Long> registrationDate = new Property<>();

    public User() {
        super(STRUCTURE);
    }

    public void hashAndSetPassword(String password) {
        this.passwordHash.set(Argon2Factory.create(Argon2Types.ARGON2id).hash(3, 102800, 1, password.toCharArray()));
    }

    public boolean verifyPassword(String attempt) {
        return Argon2Factory.create(Argon2Types.ARGON2id).verify(passwordHash.get(), attempt.toCharArray());
    }


}
```

With each entity property using the following:

```
public class Property<T> {

    private T currentValue;

    public void set(T newValue) {
        this.currentValue = newValue;
    }

    public T get() {
        return this.currentValue;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return Objects.equals(currentValue, o);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(currentValue);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(currentValue);
    }
    
}
```

We can extend or modify this Properties class and make it do more useful stuff for us, like have it record an original value, provided on creation (pulled from a database) and allow it to self-report on whether the current value of the property differs from what it was originally. Useful for determining which columns need to be updated in a database.

Most notably, this eliminates the need to create getters and setters for every new property because the Property has that functionality already. Moreover, the getters/setters are able to be overridden per-property if additional logic is needed.

I naturally ended up using this design while aiming for a more broad goal of eliminating the use of reflection/annotation processors and other black magic from my web framework. However, I’m having difficulty finding it on the internet so that I might be able to research its potential deficiencies.

Comment: "*Looking for the name of the design pattern...*" Why do you assume this is a design pattern? "*This differs from the Properties Container design pattern*" There is [no such pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern), at least under the common definition of software design patterns.

Comment: `Most notably, this eliminates the need to create getters and setters for every new property because the Property has that functionality already.` well, if you use public fields, then you never need getter/setter. Once you use `private final Property<Long> registrationDate = new Property<>();`, you need a getter as well to access it

Comment: Apologies Michael, I meant "Property Container". Have edited the question. I assumed that it was an existing design pattern because it’s so incredibly simple and seems like it could have many practical uses. I was hoping to find a name for it so that I could find people talking about its pros and cons.

Comment: @justis Property Container still doesn't seem to be a thing. I can find 1 Stack Exchange question, asking about something translated from Russian, and 1 video on YouTube which has 3 views (of which I was one), which is based on the Stack Exchange question. It's not a thing.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer It’s generally agreed that allowing outside code to access fields directly is a bad idea for maintainability/extensibility and that getters and setters are needed. I wouldn’t see the purpose in making a property private, given that the Property wrapper's primarily purpose is in allowing you to expose it.

Comment: @Michael It wasn’t my understanding that the term "design pattern" was limited to what’s explicitly listed in the Software Design Patterns wiki. My understanding was that it could be used to refer to any type of reproducible pattern of software design which can be uniquely identified.

Comment: I have a [pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect) for you. Your "Property Container" pattern is heavy, it side steps normal language mechanisms (all your properties are `public`), and you're over-engineering things based on "this could be useful" instead of "this is useful". Does not work in real life, that's why you don't see examples of it.

Comment: Then I don't understand your next sentence: `Moreover, the getters/setters are able to be overridden per-property if additional logic is needed.` Are you referring to getter/setter of `Property<T>` class? Or are you talking about implementing getter/setter for lets say `public final Property<Long> registrationDate = new Property<>();`? If you are talking about the first, then overriding would require a new class that extends `Property<T>`, which doesn't look feasible...

Comment: ...If you are talking about the latter, then having public fields, is a very bad idea, as you would need to work through the whole codebase to find every occurrence where you access the field directly and replace it with the getter/setter to make sure to use the additional logic. Lets say you want to make `username`  a mandatory field. Would you alter `Property#set` method? That would then make every other field also mandatory. If you create a setter in `User` class, then you need to find every instance where you access the field and replace it with the setter. Just be sure not to miss any

Comment: @justis The wiki may not be exhaustive but it is, at worst, *almost* exhaustive. Your definition of pattern is far more general. There is a "*reproducible pattern of software design which can be uniquely identified*" whereby people will call arbitrary variables "foo", or index counters "i". That doesn't mean that there's an "Arbitrary Identifiers Pattern". A pattern is something which someone has bothered to define, because if no one's bothered to define it then how do we know what we're talking about? Patterns are supposed to be part of our shared vocabulary.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Yes to the first. For example, if it suited my project, I might decide to create an anonymous inner class that extends Property for my password property, and move my hashing behavior into the setter. Although I’d probably just make a Password object at that point for clarity.

Comment: @Michael I agree. Perhaps I should have added "if it has a name" to the title, to account for the possibility that it did not have a name and was not part of a shared vocabulary, however, I thought it was very likely to have a name given how simple it is. Just to re-iterate, my primary goal was to be able to discover other people talking about this design so that I could uncover its benefits/deficits. I didn’t want to ask that directly when there were likely to be existing questions/answers on the subject.

Comment: And then you need the behavior of that anonymous inner class also in another class, forcing you to make it public. Then you also need some slightly altered behavior for yet another type and in the end you create a new class for every property you have, which is just not feasible

Comment: @XtremeBaumer The intended use is eliminating the need to re-write the same behavior (basic getting and setting). If behavior is different for every property, or even many properties, I’d definitely agree that this isn’t the right choice. We can go ahead and mark the Property class as final if we’re worried about it getting out of hand.

Comment: @Kayaman I used this because it was useful in my case, and I wrote about why it might be useful for others, but I agree that it’s heavy and isn’t particularly useful for most. That’s why nobody seems to be talking about it and why I’ve only just now found a need for it. Note that it is only replicating behavior present within the language to the same degree that we have standardized doing manually through the use of accessors. If you’re going to replicate language behavior anyway, one has to wonder if it might be better to write that replication once and re-use it.

Comment: My main argument against this is that once you've made something `public` in an API, you're essentially bound to keep it `public` as dependent code may break otherwise. The advantage of encapsulation is that you only expose the functionality you wish to serve, and hide the implementation details so that they may be modified later. With all of your properties `public`, you're left in a situation where you may not change the field names, nor remove ones that seem irrelevant, which really locks down your design and possible changes. This is a long comment thread though.

Comment: @Rogue Your argument is no different than an argument against public getters and setters, no? Once you’ve made them, you cannot make them non-public or change their name after all. You would only use this in cases where you were going to need public getters and setters, so I don’t see the difference. This is definitely a long comment thread, perhaps I should make a new question regarding the viability of this pattern?

Comment: Indeed that is in fact (part of) my argument. You shouldn't mindlessly create getters (and especially setters) unless you intend to provide that functionality in the first place. For instance, the `userID` should likely not be possible to set, as it would then refer to a different `User` in the system.

Comment: Your pattern isn't nearly as smart and useful as you'd want it to be, but it's not like you're writing that code for money. Continue developing and find out the weaknesses yourself. If you just want to avoid writing getters, use Lombok (or records), or design your code to avoid them.

Comment: You might consider https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ for design related questions. StackOverflow is not the proper place to evaluate your designs.

Comment: @Michael, regarding the "Arbitrary Identifiers Pattern" you may be interested in [metasyntactic variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of wrapper "variable" is used for Observable properties like StringProperty and such. Its primary use is to hold *state* and have *change* listeners, *binding* in general.

It is fruitfully used, like in JavaFX. And as you mentioned, in entity frameworks. But it definitely is stateful, non-functional, mutable.

A *pattern* name I cannot find, and I think the gang of 4 would haunt one, if calling this a pattern, other than **State**.

Comment: Holy shit, thank you so much. This is exactly the lead I was looking for. I’ll take a look at StringProperty and similar classes to learn more about this "not-a-pattern" and how to use it appropriately.

Comment: I don't think `State` perfectly fits (no internal handling of its own state), but neither would `Memento` without changes. I'd maybe vote for just calling it a single-variable `Wrapper` (but _not_ the `Adapter` pattern). In short, I don't think it is a GoF pattern at all.

Comment: @Rogue I consent, and I intended to hint that GoF would _not_ think of such a thing as independent pattern, good for something (on itself).

Answer (score 1):

Credit to [@Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1898563/michael) and [@Kayaman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2541560/kayaman) for answering in the comments: This is not a known design pattern, contrary to my expectations.

In other words, there is not a name by which people generally know to refer to what I’m calling a "Property" nor the design I’m suggesting which assumes public getters and setters are desired and uses public final fields to expose a wrapper which provides them.

This is likely because, as Kayaman pointed out, it’s pretty heavy while being not terribly useful.